# Clojure multimethod giving unexpected null pointer

Tags: clojure, multimethod

I'm having a hard time getting the multimethods in Clojure to work as I would expect. A distillation of my code is as follows.

```
(defn commandType [_ command] (:command-type command))

(defmulti testMulti commandType)

(defmethod testMulti :one [game command] (str "blah"))

(defmethod testMulti :default [& args] "Cannot understand")

(testMulti "something" {:command-type :one})

(commandType "something" {:command-type :one})
```

Now I would expect here to have the method commandType called on the arguments which would of course return :one which should send it to the first defmethod but instead I get a null pointer exception. Even the simplest invocation of a multimethod I could come up with gives me a null pointer:

```
(defmulti simpleMulti :key)

(defmethod simpleMulti "basic" [params] "basic value")

(simpleMulti {:key "basic"})
```

And yet the example in the clojure docs located [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/defmulti) works fine. Is there something fundamental I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can see, it works.

Given

```
(defmulti testMulti (fn [_ command] (:command-type command)))

(defmethod testMulti :one [game command] (str "blah"))

(defmethod testMulti :default [& args] "Cannot understand")
```

then

```
(testMulti "something" {:command-type :one})
; "blah"

(testMulti "something" {:command-type :two})
; "Cannot understand"

(testMulti "something" 5)
; "Cannot understand"
```

as expected.

I reset the REPL before running the above afresh.

And the simple example works too. Given

```
(defmulti simpleMulti :key)

(defmethod simpleMulti "basic" [params] "basic value")
```

then

```
(simpleMulti {:key "basic"})
; "basic value"
```

Comment: You're right. They worked after I started up a new REPL.